# Jersey servlet mapping confusion

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jersey-2.0

Can somebody please explain in plain English how this works (or at least why my structure doesn't)? I want a function called `ExportLicenseInfo` in my Jersey servlet resource, which I have called ExportResource, to map to `http://example.com/myApp/export/software_licenses.{year}-{month}.{format}`, for example: `http://example.com/myApp/export/software_licenses_2013-10.csv`

Servlet config in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.app.ExportApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My servlet mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExportServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/export</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My code with `@Path` annotations:

```
@Path("/export")
public class ExportResource {

    ...

    @GET
    @Produces({"text/csv", "application/json"})
    @Path("/software_licenses_{year: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}-{month: [0-1][0-9]}.{format}")
    public String ExportLicenseInfo( ... ) {
    ...
    }
```

When I try to access the resource, I get a 404. Jersey trace log:

```
Feb 21, 2014 2:41:46 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 6 * LoggingFilter - Request received on thread http-bio-8080-exec-67
6 > GET http://localhost:8080/app/export/software_licenses_2013-10.csv
6 > host: localhost:8080
6 > connection: keep-alive
6 > cache-control: max-age=0
6 > accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
6 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
6 > accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
6 > accept-language: en
6 > cookie: JSESSIONID=DB64E0B066BDEE8CABFC94686AD6ACDC.test; JSESSIONIDSSO=61B51CEED61F8F6CE8A8DB46B38BAC9F; i18next=en

Feb 21, 2014 2:41:46 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 6 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread http-bio-8080-exec-67
6 < 404
```

Comment: Your `ExportResource` is not a Servlet.

Comment: Yeah; I know that. My servlet is a jersey servlet that calls the package.

Comment: Oh, and I'm getting a 404. I'll update my question.

Comment: That's not a jersey servlet. And obviously, you're mapping your `"/export"` path to an nonexistent servlet. That's why you get the 404. Instead, show your web.xml configurations for your jersey servlet.

Comment: Assuming that `ExportServlet` is mapped to jersey rest dispatcher servlet, you are mapping `/export` to your rest service, which responds `/export` within that path, so I think the correct url of your service is `http://example.com/myApp/export/export/software_licenses_2013-10.csv`.

Comment: That's what I thought might be the case, but I'm still getting a 404 when I try that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping the jersey servlet like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ExportServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/export/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just finished getting that working using that pattern. In my Servlet Resource, I also had to change the `@Path` annotation for the class from `'/export'` to `'/'`.